# cant access html files in wwwroot in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, root

After a MS Update for RC1, I created a brand new c# mvc empty project in VS 2015 and placed an index.html into the wwwroot directory.

Howvever, I cannot seem to access this file in debug mode. I can access the "api" directory where I have my api controller files which is in the root directory.

The .bowerrc file has the default of:
"directory": "wwwroot/lib"

Any idea?

[image]